# generating subprocess.call arguments from a list

Tags: python

I am using the subprocess module to execute a command line software with arguments but I am running into a bit of trouble when it comes to feeding it a list of arguments .

Here is what I am doing :

```
subprocess.call([rv,"[",rv_args[0],rv_args[1],"]",])
```

This works fine and **len(rv_args) == 2** , now I would like to generate this :

```
if len(rv_args) == 4 :
    subprocess.call([rv,"[",rv_args[0],rv_args[1],"]","[",rv_args[2],rv_args[3],"]",])
```

then

```
if len(rv_args) == 6 :
    return subprocess.call([rv,"[",rv_args[0],rv_args[1],"]","[",rv_args[2],rv_args[3],"]","[",rv_args[4],rv_args[5],"]"])
```

etc .. etc ..

Of course I don't want to hard code it, but generate it on the fly, what you be the best way ?

cheers,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Comment: What do you want to happen if your list has an odd length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
rv = "command"
rv_args = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]


def get_arguments(rv, rv_args):
    arguments = [rv]
    for i in xrange(0, len(rv_args), 2):
        arguments += ["["] + rv_args[i:i+2] + ["]"]

    return arguments

print get_arguments(rv, rv_args)
```

returns:

```
['command', '[', 1, 2, ']', '[', 3, 4, ']', '[', 5, 6, ']', '[', 7, 8, ']', '[', 9, 10, ']']
```